# How to check if page exists using page alias in D7?

Tags: 7, uri, path-aliases

In D7, how do I check whether a page exists by page alias? I've found some guy asking [the same very question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780884/drupal-path-alias-exist-or-not) but I have problems with using menu_valid_path() (or drupal_valid_path() in D7) function. It always returns TRUE, no matter how weird a path I pass to it. Here is a sample code:

```php
if(drupal_valid_path($GLOBALS['base_url'] . '/contacts')) //this exists
{
    print_r('Exists!');
}
if(drupal_valid_path($GLOBALS['base_url'] . '/weird_alias')) //this doesn't exist
{
    print_r('Exists!');
}
```

I get two "exists" despite the fact that /weird_alias page doesn't exist and returns a "page not found" error. I'm extremely reluctant to use drupal_http_request() because there are a lot of unnecessary things like headers, timeouts etc. Shouldn't there be an easier way to check internal paths?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the code for [`drupal_valid_path()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21path.inc/function/drupal_valid_path/7) it passes the alias through [`url_is_external()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/url_is_external/7), which considers paths with a `http://` prefix to be external. The function defaults to allow access to these sorts of paths and simply returns that fact; it does not check whether the 'external' url exists.

Since you're adding `$GLOBALS['base_url']` to the alias it will appear to be external; you just need to pass the alias into the function without the base URL attached:

```
if(drupal_valid_path('weird_alias')) {
  // This code is never run
  print_r('Exists!');

}
```

Comment: Oh. :-) I've been stupid. Didn't even think of the fact it should be without 'http'. Thanks.

Comment: There is also an issue with whether the path is an alias or not. If the path is an alias, drupal_lookup_path('source','$path) might be needed to get a valid result. See this post: [http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2013/03/05/drupal-7-check-if-a-path-exists/]

Answer (score 2):

Just try this

```
if(drupal_valid_path('contacts') == 1) //this exists
{
    print_r('Exists!');
}
if(drupal_valid_path('weird_alias') == 1) //this doesn't exist
{
    print_r('Exists!');
}
```

Comment: Tnx. Most unfortunately I can't tag 2 answers as 'Answered' so I had to choose the one above because it came earlier. But your answer is valuable too. :-)